# Google API Libraries for +1 or takeout?

Tags: google-api, google-plus-one

I was working on a chrome extension that uses a user's +1 URLs as a bookmark backend. As of now, there is [no API](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=83) for accessing my own +1d urls. However [Google Takeout offers such an option](https://www.google.com/takeout/#custom%3aplus_one). In short, could someone guide me to :

a) any chrome extension that interfaces with Google Takeout (in the absence of a takeout API)
b) a scraper that would scrape http://plus.google.com/me/plusones

Answer (score 3):

You can try parsing the data from this.

`https://plus.google.com/_/plusone/get?oid=<google-plus-id>`

Comment: I've actually used this endpoint in my [bookplus extension](https://github.com/captn3m0/bookplus/blob/master/main.js#L139-142). But its unofficial, and may break any second. It is also mentioned in the bug report I linked in the question.